# How to apply a custom python function to paired data in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wish to compute a custom function (in my case the Hausdorff distance) between two tensors in TensorFlow. However, I still miss something about the use of `tf.map` function.

In particular, I wish to compute a custom function between elements of a batch, and this function is a python function. When I want to use the function, I do:

```
# get a batch of images and ground truth segmentation masks from the dataset
input_data, y_true = from_dataset(...)

# compute predicted segmentation mask:
y_pred = myCNN(input_data) 

# compute hausdorff distance for each element of the batch:
list_of_hds = sess.run(hausdorff_distance(y_pred, y_true))
```

My current implementation of the Hausdorff distance:

```
from medpy.metric.binary import hd
import tensorflow as tf


def hausdorff_distance(mask1, mask2):
    def _py_hd(m1, m2):
        where1 = np.argwhere(m1)
        where2 = np.argwhere(m2)
        return hd(where1, where2)
    tf_hd = tf.map_fn(lambda el:
                      tf.py_function(func=_py_hd, inp=[el[0], el[1]],
                                     Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32], name='hausdorff_distance'),
                      elems=[mask1, mask2])
    return tf_hd
```

However, if I get it right, **this implementation is WRONG**. In fact, it would apply the HD to mask1 and mask2 altogether. Instead, I want to obtain a list of HDs between each element of the batches. In practice, I want the list: `l = [HD(mask1[0], mask2[0]), HD(mask1[1], mask2[1]), ... HD(mask1[N], mask2[N])]`.

What do I miss? Did I misunderstand the functioning of `tf.map`?

Thank you,
G.

---

**P.S.** this implementation uses TensorFlow 1.14, though I guess things should be similar for TensorFlow > 2.

---

**Edit:**
I found a possible solution, which I leave in the comments below. Any help is still more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution, which I hope is correct. I leave it here for who could be interested.

```
from medpy.metric.binary import hd
import tensorflow as tf

def hausdorff_distance(mask1, mask2):
    """Compute the average Hausdorff distance for the patient (in pixels), between mask1 and mask2."""

    def _py_hd(m1, m2):
        """Python function to compute HD between the two n-dimensional masks"""
        m1, m2 = np.array(m1), np.array(m2)
        num_elems = len(m1)
        assert len(m2) == num_elems

        # remove last channel, if it is == 1:
        if len(m1.shape) == 4 and m1.shape[-1] == 1:
            m1, m2 = np.squeeze(m1, axis=-1), np.squeeze(m2, axis=-1)

        return hd(m1, m2)

    # map _py_hd(.) to every element on the batch axis:
    tf_hd = tf.py_function(func=_py_hd, inp=[mask1, mask2],
                           Tout=[tf.float32], name='hausdorff_distance'),

    # return the average HD in the batch:
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf_hd)
```